# Sets for which only some open coverings have finite subcoverings

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I am  about halfway through my first course in analysis and have a question about compact sets. Recall that set $S$ in a metric space is said to compact if and only if **every** open covering of $S$ contains a finite subcovering of $S$.

That *every* is necessary is strange to me. **My question:** what sets $Q$ both have open coverings with finite subcoverings and have open coverings without finite subcoverings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, there's a lot of them. For example, every open set $U \subseteq M$ has that property since $U$ is a cover itself and has finite subcover (itself). However, open sets are usually not compact.

As a matter of fact, **any** subset of $M$ which is not compact has that property, since $M$ itself is an open cover for any subset $U \subseteq M$; and $M$ is the corresponding finite open subcover. However, if $U$ is not compact, then there necessarily exists some open cover which does not have a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

Think about examples as $$\mathbb R=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;(-n,n)$$

Comment: @DonThousand: What was the aim of your edit? This is not an open covering now.

Comment: I have not changed the contents of your answer at all, just the formatting. Check the edit history. I was confused since the answer is not an open covering, but I didn't fix it since it isn't my answer.

Comment: @DonThousand: It is written that my open intervals $]-n,n[$ are now closed ones $[-n,n]$.

Comment: @DonThousand: Perhaps the issue is that I used incorrect notation for open ones here, and that $(-n,n)$ is the correct one?

Comment: The notation $]-n,n[$ clearly denotes the open interval and is (as far as I know) common in the French literature. In the U.S., $(-n,n)$ is more common. In both cases, $[-n,n]$ is the closed interval, so the edit is wrong. I'll change it to parentheses, but if you prefer the reversed square bracket notation you can edit it back to that.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thank you for your intervention: I will let the parentheses since I think the U.S. notations are more suitable here.

Comment: @AndreasBlass My apologies, I thought it was a typo.

Comment: @DonThousand: No problem.